# Best Practice for captcha based protection against D.O.S to Nginx Proxy

Tags: ddos

The idea is explained [here](http://dos-attacks.com/2011/02/02/captcha-based-protection-against-http-get-ddos-attacks/)

In simple words, Nginx Proxy plays the role of load balance and transmits the HTTP/HTTPS requests to servers.

If the number of request times within a certain period from an individual IP exceeds a threshold, it will trigger a captcha for the upcoming requests.

And the end-user must input the correct captcha code before he can continue to access the site.

Do you know any open source / free NGINX module for this usage?
I searched on the Internet and here is one of them: https://github.com/snbuback/nginx
seems it needs modification.

Any suggestion / experience is welcome, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, captcha will only annoy your real users. For this problem I'd rather use the [testcookie-nginx-module](http://kyprizel.github.com/testcookie-nginx-module/).

Comment: Thanks, I don't quite understand how it works from its sequence charts. Will it prevent Search Engine Crawler to parse my site?

Comment: Well, it depends on your imagination mostly :) I guess that correct `robots.txt` file would be a better option to filter out search bots. In addition to this, you can use nginx rules - [like this way](http://serverfault.com/questions/382946/blocking-good-bots-in-nginx-with-multiple-conditions-for-certain-off-limits-ur).